# ImportError: Missing Required Dependencies [ 'dateutil' ]

Tags: importerror, python-dateutil, pymc3

I tried to use a code, where I use pymc3, but I get an error: ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['dateutil']. I installed dateutil, but it still gives me this error.

Comment: You'll probably need to provide more information about exactly how you are calling pymc3. What OS are you using? Is it possible that you installed dateutil in python 2 but you're trying to use python 3? How did you install these?

Comment: You may also benefit from looking at the output of `pip freeze`

Comment: I only have python 2.7 on my Mac, which is an OS X El  Capitan. I call pymc3 by saying "import pymc3". I installed dateutil by using pip install and that came up with an error of not finding it, so I used easy_install python-dateutil and that worked. I still got the error though. @Paul

Comment: What would pip freeze do? @Paul

Comment: `pip freeze` lists all installed packages. `pip install python-dateutil` is how to use pip to install dateutil

Comment: How did you install `pymc3`? `pip install` should have pulled in all dependencies, including `matplotlib` (which in turn pulls in `python-dateutil`).

Comment: I did use pip install to install pymc3 @Paul

Comment: Does `python-dateutil` show up in `pip freeze`?

Comment: Then the problem is that whatever code path you're invoking pymc3 on is different from the one that `python-dateutil` is installed on. In terms of debugging, you could probably play around with printing out `sys.path`, to track down exactly what path your libraries are being pulled from. Alternatively, it may be worthwhile to just install Anaconda, which bundles up a lot of dependencies together for you.

Comment: I have Anaconda installed , and panda. I'll try debugging it. Thank you for your help! @Paul